# jQuery Hide and show only source file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm only using a very small portion of the jQuery library: just the `hide()` and `show()`.

I have seen threads that has made the equivalent in javascript but the animation on the jQuery version is really nice. I don't know if it possible just to have the jQuery code for that only.

Comment: Where is jQuery _park_?

Comment: @Satpal He typo'd "part".

Comment: If that is all you want jQuery for, maybe its better to write that functionality yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The best (also as far as performance goes) practice for a simple show/hide feature is to introduce a CSS class, like

```
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

And if you have this class, you can toggle it on an element using the `classList` property. Here are some usages.

```
element.classList.remove("hidden");
element.classList.add("hidden");
element.classList.toggle("hidden");
```

One of the biggest advantage is that you won't loose the original `display`. If you have defined for example `inline-block`, then using the `block/none` CSS approach will reset your `display` to `block`.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple Javascript to show and hide.

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Set property display as none to hide the div

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display="none";
```

Set property display as block or any other to show the div

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display="block";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some CSS animation using a checkbox, a label, and a list, using:

- `transition`
- `transform: scaleY`
- `opacity`
- `max-height`

The rulsets can be applied to accentuate jQuery/JavaScript animations as well.

#### SNIPPET

```css
dl {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  border: 3px ridge grey;
  transition: opacity 1.6s, max-height 1s, transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#list1 {
  display: none;
}
#list1:checked + dl {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 2000px;
  border: 3px ridge grey;
  transition: opacity 1.6s, max-height 1s, transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<label for='list1'>List</label>
<input id='list1' type='checkbox'>
<dl>
  <dt>Title</dt>
  <dd>Item</dd>
  <dd>Item</dd>
  <dd>Item</dd>
  <dd>Item</dd>
  <dd>Item</dd>
  <dd>Item</dd>
  <dd>Item</dd>
  <dd>Item</dd>
</dl>
```